# Linking errors when using clang++ with -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping on windows with mingw

Tags: c++, linker, clang, mingw, code-coverage

I recently changed my toolchain from gcc to clang on a windows machine using mingw. Everything is working fine so far, but now I'm trying to integrate the code coverage functionality offered by llvm directly (not the gcov interface) and I'm struggling hard with that task.

After adding the two compiler options `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` I started having weird linking errors. Looking into the problem I found some hints, that I need to add `-fprofile-instr-generate` to the linker and provide the compiler-rt library `libclang_rt.profile-i386.a` (I try to compile for 32Bit) to the linker as well. But even after doing this the linking errors of multiple symbol definitions and undefined symbols stay.

The coverage with `llvm-cov gcov` and the compiler option `--coverage` is working fine though. I just think it would be nicer to stay within the llvm environment and that I would not need to use additional tools like gcovr to create the coverage reports. Also I heard that the original llvm tooling provides better coverage results...

I'm using mingw32 with clang 10.

I also found the suggestion to use `clang-cl` on a windows machine instead of `clang++` but this makes me run into other problems, since I havent compiled for msvc before...

Do you have any suggestions on this?
Thank you :)

**Update**

The minimal example (in combination with googletest in directory `..\googletest`):

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
project(minimal_example)

set(COMPILE_OPTIONS 
  -m32
  -O0
  -g

  #the problem starts here
  -fprofile-instr-generate=foo.profraw
  -fcoverage-mapping
)

add_compile_options("${COMPILE_OPTIONS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "-m32 -fprofile-instr-generate=foo.profraw")

link_directories("C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/clang/10.0.0/lib/windows")

include_directories("../googletest")
add_subdirectory(../googletest ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/unittest)

add_executable(minimal_example MyExampleMain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(minimal_example gtest_main clang_rt.profile-i386)
```

MyExampleMain.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(TestSuite1, Test1)
{
  int x(0);
  int y(3);
  if(x==5)
  {
      y=0;
  }
  EXPECT_EQ(3, y);  
}
```

I invoke cmake with: `cmake -Bbuild -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang`

The resulting linking error complety fill the standard cmd buffer.

An example is: `` C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\ld: lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.obj): in function `ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_N7testing8internal12CodeLocationEESt10_Select1stISB_ESt4lessIS5_ESaISB_EE3endEv':
C:\/msys64\mingw32\include\c++\10.1.0\bits\stl_tree.h:1011: undefined reference to `__profc__ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_N7testing8internal12CodeLocationEESt10_Select1stISB_ESt4lessIS5_ESaISB_EE3endEv' ``

By overlooking the errors of the minimal example I couldn't find any of the multiple symbol definitions linking error that I observed in my production code...

**UPDATE 2**

The linking errors seem to be related to the googletest framework only. When compiling a simple program without googletest like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x(0);
  if (x == 1)
  {
    std::cout<<"This is impossible"<<std::endl;
  } 
  else
  {
    std::cout<<"This is more likely"<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program gets linked and executed correctly. There is also a `foo.profraw` file created. But the created output profraw file is empty though. Which shouldn't be the case I guess.

Comment: Are the linker errors so weird you can't share them? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I added some updates in the main post. Just to inform you in case you don't get an automated update...

Comment: are all your code and libraries built with the same gcc c++ 11 abi https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: I guess so. All the googletest libraries are build with the same compiler as being part of the project. I don't use gcc though, but clang instead. I can't speak for the system libraries, but the fact, that the code builds without the both compiler options and the other way around without linking googletest just fine, makes me think that the system libraries fit. The c++ std does not matter to the linking errors. I can set -std to c++11, c++14, c++17 or not define it (as in the example). The errors are persistent.

Comment: how do I make sure though?

Comment: Those are the mingw packages I have installed:

Comment: mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-clang 10.0.0-1 [installed]
    C language family frontend for LLVM (mingw-w64)

mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-clang-analyzer 10.0.0-1 [installed]
    A source code analysis framework (mingw-w64)

mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-clang-tools-extra 10.0.0-1 [installed]
    Extra tools built using Clang's tooling APIs (mingw-w64)

mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-compiler-rt 10.0.0-1 [installed]
    Runtime libraries for Clang and LLVM (mingw-w64)

mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-libblocksruntime 0.4.1-1 [installed]
    compiler-rt Blocks runtime library for Clang (mingw-w64)

Comment: There is an ABI mismatch. The solution is described here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/12/setting-up-clang-on-windows/